# Summing integers across records in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using the Spark console in the Cloudera QuickStart VM. In the sample output below you will see two columns of data obtained by using the code:

```
channel_views.filter(lambda x: "XYZ" == x[1]).take(10)
```

The goal is to collapse this dataset so that it displays just one unique line of "XYZ" and the corresponding sum of all the numbers pertaining to "XYZ". How do we obtain this?

Sample output:

```
[(1038, u'XYZ'),
(415, u'XYZ'),
(100, u'XYZ'),
(597, u'XYZ'),
(786, u'XYZ'),
(163, u'XYZ'),
(884, u'XYZ'),
(345, u'XYZ'),
(534, u'XYZ'),
(947, u'XYZ')]
```

Comment: provide some sample input for us to work with.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out, Pangea. However, AChampion's below work helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reduce the output, probably the simplest is to convert (`map`) to key, value pair and then `reduceByKey`, e.g.:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([(1038, u'XYZ'), ...])
>>> (rdd.filter(lambda x: "XYZ" == x[1])
...  .map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
...  .reduceByKey(add).collect())
[('XYZ', 5809)]
```

Or you could define a more complicated function in `reduce`:

```
>>> (rdd.filter(lambda x: "XYZ" == x[1])
...  .reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]))
(5809, 'XYZ')
```